# Iterating over pandas groupby object

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, iterator

The following code executes using python 2.x but not python 3.x .

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
gb = df.groupby(['style'])
for a, b in gb:
    #any command, iteration fails
```

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 143, in factorize
    sorter = uniques.argsort()
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1250, in get_iterator
    splitter = self._get_splitter(data, axis=axis)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1256, in _get_splitter
    comp_ids, _, ngroups = self.group_info
  File "pandas/src/properties.pyx", line 34, in pandas.lib.cache_readonly.__get__ (pandas/lib.c:41917)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1365, in group_info
    comp_ids, obs_group_ids = self._get_compressed_labels()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1373, in _get_compressed_labels
    all_labels = [ping.labels for ping in self.groupings]
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1373, in <listcomp>
    all_labels = [ping.labels for ping in self.groupings]
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2023, in labels
    self._make_labels()
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2034, in _make_labels
    labels, uniques = algos.factorize(self.grouper, sort=self.sort)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 152, in factorize
    lambda x: isinstance(x,string_types) ]
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 151, in <listcomp>
    np.sort(np.array([ e for i, e in enumerate(uniques) if f(e) ],dtype=object)) for f in [ lambda x: not isinstance(x,string_types),
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 799, in sort
    a.sort(axis, kind, order)
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

The variable `data` is a list of dictionaries and both data frames created from python 2 and python 3 show the same results. Why does python 3 not allow me to iterate over the `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` object held in `gb` ?

EDIT:

Here is an example of a dictionary within the data

```
{'period': '2013-12-30 00:00:00-2014-08-31 23:59:59', 'size': '40', 'color': 'GREEN', 'style': ('WEDGES', 'PLATFORM OPEN TOE', 'SLINGBACK', 'SKY HIGH (>96)'), 'sales': 2.0}
```

Comment: could you give an example of a dictionary you're using? your error says that they are not consistent and that therefore python 3 can not decide how to order a string vs an integer

Comment: @VictorSmt i updated it with an example, thank you for your help

Comment: @JohnSmith: Do you actually get the TypeError with the `data` dict you posted? (I'm not getting the error using Python3.4, pandas 0.15.2.)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error... Can you tell me what gb is when you print it?

Comment: @VictorSmt It's a fairly large data set it would be unreasonable to post it all, however you guys are correct a subset of the data (a selection of dictionaries) work, so the problem must be within the data, however python 2 still iterated over it given the same data... Do any cases come to mind where different fields within a dictionary would cause this error? Or would you suggest a debugging approach as to how to single out the section of data that is not cooperating? Thanks again

Comment: @unutbu it's multiple dictionaries, please see my comment above this it wouldn't let me tag multiple users, thank you

Comment: In Python2, strings are comparable to ints: `'foo' > 999`. In CPython, ["Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). This proved to be nonsensical in it arbitrariness and a pitfall to new users. So, in Python3 strings are NOT comparable to ints. It raises the exact `TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()` that you see. However, pandas has code to deal with this issue (see algorithms.py, line 151 for example), so it is unclear to me how this error is getting reached given `df`.

Comment: Try running `python -m pdb /path/to/script.py`. This will drop you in the pdb debugger. Press `c` to continue. This will break when an exception is reached. Now inspect the value of `a` by typing `p a`. This will give you a clue what values in the `data` dict are causing the problem. Press `q` to quit the debugger.

Comment: @unutbu turns out there was an int being produced in a few select tuples within certain dictionaries that shouldn't be there.. the string/int comparison explains why it works python2 but not 3, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @JohnSmith did you solve this I am running Python 3 with 4 level multiindex and get same error?

Answer (score 0):

The `style` looks like it should be a tuple of strings. It looks like you have some ints in some of the tuples. One solution would be to convert any non strings to strings before grouping

```
gb = df.groupby(by=lambda x: tuple(str(i) for i in data[x]['style']))
```